# PHP __DIR__ displays system root

Tags: php, apache, active-directory, dir, document-root

today i got some confuseing error
my `__DIR__` is pointing to the System root directory, but i need the Apache2 root-dir

i tried to add

```
php_admin_value open_basedir /var/www/html
```

in apache2.conf and sites-aviable/000-default.conf

is there any option in php.ini?

i am using

PHP:

```
PHP 5.5.9-1ubuntu4.3
```

Apache:

```
Server version: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu)
Server built:   Jul 22 2014 14:36:38
```

In my case

```
__DIR__ == "/var/www/html/"
```

May you can help me

Answer (score 0):

There's no real way to do that. `__DIR__` is an absolute path to the current file. There are many reasons you need to know this and it cannot be changed.

[open_basedir](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.open-basedir) is a directive to restrict what files PHP and Apache have access to in a given site. It's most commonly used in shared hosting environments to keep user A from accessing user B's files.

Comment: im realy nooby in what file has i to go; normaly in the 000-default.conf

Answer (score 0):

`__DIR__` is the path to the file which this code is located in. So if your script is in the root directory, `__DIR__` would work as you want it to.